# Unable to get Response Parameters in Notification and Success url SOFORT API

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, payum

```
public function sofyAction()
{
    $args = [ 'config_key' => $this->getConfigKey() ];
    $sofy = new Api($args);

    $helper = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('ViewHelperManager')->get('ServerUrl');
    $successUrl = $helper($this->url()->fromRoute('sofort_response'));

    $params = [
        'amount' => 1500,
        'currency_code' => 'EUR',
        'reason' => 'Vouhcer Order',
        'success_url' => $successUrl,
        'customer_protection' => false,
        'notification_url' => 'MY_PRIVATE_RESPONSE_URL',
    ];

    $trans = $sofy->createTransaction($params);
    return $this->redirect()->toUrl($trans['payment_url']);
}
```

How to get response and transaction ID as given it API document in Notification URL and on success URL too , please unable to find any help or guide for it ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to let Payum do notification related job for you. To do so you either:

- have to create manually a notification token using Payum's token factory (I am not sure it is present in the Zend module, it is quite old). Use the token as notification_url. Nothing more. Sofort will send a request to that url and Payum [does the rest](https://github.com/Payum/PayumModule/blob/master/src/Payum/PayumModule/Controller/NotifyController.php).
- Make sure the token factory is passed to a gateway object and later is injected to capture action object. Leave the notification_url field empty and Payum will [generate](https://github.com/Payum/Payum/blob/64fb6453b778279a91c40b766ef9d59f1dcc2c62/src/Payum/Sofort/Action/CaptureAction.php#L41) a new one.
- use your own url as notification one and add there all the info you need (as a query string).  I wouldn't recommend it since you expose sensitive data and once could try to exploit it.

Answer (score 0):

I **solved** it this way by appending `?trx=-TRANSACTION-` with success and notification url and than in response i recieved Transaction id as parameter and later loaded TransactionData with that `transactionId` . Payum Token way wasn't working for me ! Obiously had to use its config key to create **`Payum/Sofort/Api`** isnstance,

**REQUEST:**

```
$args = [ 'config_key' => $sofortConfigKey ];
$sofortPay = new Api($args);

// ?trx=-TRANSACTION- will append transacion ID as response param !
$params = [
    'amount' => $coupon['price'],
    'currency_code' => $coupon['currency'],
    'reason' => $coupon['description'],
    'success_url' => $successUrl.'?trx=-TRANSACTION-',
    'abort_url' => $abortUrl.'?trx=-TRANSACTION-',
    'customer_protection' => false,
    'notification_url' => '_URL_'.'?trx=-TRANSACTION-',
];

$transactionParams = $sofortPay->createTransaction($params);
return $this->redirect()->toUrl($transactionParams['payment_url']);
```

**RESPONSE:**

```
$args = [ 'config_key' => $configKey ];
$sofy = new Api( $args );

$transNumber = $this->getRequest()->getQuery('trx');
$fields = $sofy->getTransactionData($transNumber);
```

Took help from API document. Payum documentation is worst. [SOFORT API DOC](https://www.sofort.com/integrationCenter-eng-DE/content/view/full/2513#h3-3)

Comment: could you please, give some info - what response should get `sofort` on notification request?